# Jsf Primefaces Remember fileUpload name on back page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In page 1 I chose a image then I go to page 2, then I go back to page 1 but I don't see the image that I was selected. How I can get in image1 the image that I was selected?

page1:

```
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGrid id="grid1" columns="3">
    <p:fileUpload id="image1"  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"  value="#{bean.image1}" mode="simple" auto="true" skinSimple="true"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Next" ajax="false" action="page2"         disabled="false" />
    </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

in page2

```
    <p:commandButton value="Back" ajax="false" action="page1" disabled="false" />
```

Comment: First check if, on pressing back, your page comes from cache. If not, you are at a loss. Security wise impossible. If it does come from cache, I'm not sure what the browser and/or component behaviour should be.

Comment: The scope is <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>